# Defining incremental environments without running into overlapping instances

Tags: haskell, overlapping-instances

How to define an environment to which we can add "capabilities" without running into overlapping instances?

Suppose we have the following data-types and type-classes:

```
type Name = String

data Fruit = Orange | Pear | Apple

data Vegetable = Cucumber | Carrot | Spinach

data Legume = Lentils | Chickpeas | BlackEyedPeas

class HasFruit e where
    getFruit :: e -> Name -> Maybe Fruit

class HasVegetable e where
    getVegetable :: e -> Name -> Maybe Vegetable

class HasLegume e where
    getLegume :: e -> Name -> Maybe Legume
```

Now we would like to define a couple of functions that require certain ingredients from the environment:

```
data Smootie

mkSmoothie :: (HasFruit e, HasVegetable e) => e -> Smootie
mkSmoothie = undefined

data Salad

mkSalad :: (HasVegetable e, HasLegume e) => e -> Salad
mkSalad = undefined
```

And we define some instances for `Has*`:

```
instance HasFruit [Fruit] where
    getFruit = undefined

instance HasVegetable [Vegetable] where
    getVegetable = undefined

instance HasLegume [Legume] where
    getLegume = undefined
```

And finally, we would like to define a function that prepares a smoothie and a salad:

```
cook :: (Smootie, Salad)
cook = let ingredients = undefined in
    (mkSmoothie ingredients, mkSalad ingredients)
```

Now the first question is, what to pass as ingredients to that the instances defined above can be used? My first solution to this was to use tuples:

```
instance HasFruit e0 => HasFruit (e0, e1, e2) where
    getFruit (e0, _, _) = getFruit e0

instance HasVegetable e1 => HasVegetable (e0, e1, e2) where
    getVegetable (_, e1, _) = getVegetable e1

instance HasLegume e2 => HasLegume (e0, e1, e2) where
    getLegume (_, _, e2) = getLegume e2

cook :: (Smootie, Salad)
cook = let ingredients = ([Orange], [Cucumber], [BlackEyedPeas]) in
    (mkSmoothie ingredients, mkSalad ingredients)
```

This, even though cumbersome, works. But now assume that we
decide to add a `mkStew`, which requires some `HasMeat` instance.
Then we'd have to change all the instances above. Furthermore,
if we would like to use `mkSmothie` in isolation, we cannot just
pass `([Orange], [Cucumber])` since there is no instance defined
for it.

I could define:

```
data Sum a b = Sum a b
```

and instances like:

```
instance HasFruit e0 => HasFruit (Sum e0 e1) where
    getFruit (Sum e0 _) = getFruit e0

instance HasVegetable e1 => HasVegetable (Sum e0 e1) where
    getVegetable (Sum _ e1) = getVegetable e1

instance HasLegume e1 => HasLegume (Sum e0 e1) where
    getLegume (Sum _ e1) = getLegume e1
```

But the following won't work (No instance for `HasVegetable [Legume]`):

```
cook1 :: (Smootie, Salad)
cook1 = let ingredients = Sum [Orange] (Sum [Cucumber] [BlackEyedPeas]) in
    (mkSmoothie ingredients, mkSalad ingredients)
```

And This instance will overlap!

```
instance HasVegetable e0 => HasVegetable (Sum e0 e1) where
    getVegetable (Sum e0 e1) = getVegetable e0
```

Is there a way to solve this problem in an elegant way?

Comment: [The Expression Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem); [Data Types a la Carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the present `Sum` instances is that we don't know whether the object we are looking for is to the left or to the right.

Here's the plan: each component of the environment should declare what capabilities it offers so that we can then search for it.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/162a74cce510741fda1775541a0a9800) of this answer.

## Declaring capabilities

As environments will be composed, we will need a (type-level) data structure to carry the capabilities from their different parts. We will use a binary tree, so we can preserve the structure of components.

```
-- Tree of capabilities (ingredient categories)
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Capabilities associated with an environment are declared via this type family.

```
type family Contents basket :: Tree *

type instance Contents [Fruit] = 'Leaf Fruit
type instance Contents [Vegetable] = 'Leaf Vegetable
type instance Contents [Legume] = 'Leaf Legume

-- Pair of environments
data a :& b = a :& b  -- "Sum" was confusing

-- The capabilities of a pair are the pair of their capabilities.
type instance Contents (a :& b) = 'Node (Contents a) (Contents b)

-- e.g., Contents ([Fruit] :& [Vegetable]) = 'Node ('Leaf Fruit) ('Leaf Vegetable)
```

## Looking up a capability

As mentioned at the beginning, when encountering a pair `:&`, we will need to tell whether to find the capability in the left or right component. Thus we start with a function (at the type level) that returns `True` if the capability can be found in the tree.

```
type family In (x :: *) (ys :: Tree *) :: Bool where
  In x (Leaf y) = x == y
  In x (Node l r) = In x l || In x r

type family x == y :: Bool where
  x == x = 'True
  x == y = 'False
```

### The `Has` class

This class now has a superclass constraint: that the capability we are looking for is indeed available.

```
class (In item (Contents basket) ~ 'True)
      => Has item basket where
  get :: basket -> Name -> Maybe item
```

It may seem superfluous, because instance resolution would fail anyway if the capability is not found, but a precise superclass constraint has benefits:

- preventing mistakes: the compiler will complain earlier if something is missing;
- a form of documentation, informing us of when an instance may exist.

### Leaf instances

```
instance Has Fruit [Fruit] where
  get = (...)

instance Has Vegetable [Vegetable] where
  get = (...)

instance Has Legume [Legume] where
  get = (...)
```

We don't need to write dubious instances like `Has Fruit [Vegetable]`; we actually can't: they would contradict the superclass constraint.

### Instance for `(:&)`

We need to defer to a new class, `PairHas` that will discriminate on the result of the `In` predicate on both sides to determine which part of the environment to zoom in.

```
instance PairHas item a b (In item (Contents a)) (In item (Contents b))
         => Has item (a :& b) where
  get = getPair
```

Again, we make the superclass constraints extra precise about the intent of `PairHas`. `inA` and `inB` can only be instantiated with `In item (Contents a)` and `In item (Contents b)` respectively, and their disjunction should be `True`, meaning that `item` can be found in at least one of them.

```
class ( In item (Contents a) ~ inA
      , In item (Contents b) ~ inB
      , (inA || inB) ~ 'True)
      => PairHas item a b inA inB where
  getPair :: (a :& b) -> Name -> Maybe item
```

Of course we have two instances to go left and right respectively, using recursive `Has` constraints (note that `Has` provides one equality via its own superclass constraint).

```
instance ( Has item a
         , In item (Contents b) ~ 'False)
         => PairHas item a b 'True 'False where
  getPair (a :& _) = get a

instance ( In item (Contents a) ~ 'False
         , Has item b)
         => PairHas item a b 'False 'True where
  getPair (_ :& b) = get b
```

What if both sides have the same capability? We shall consider that an error and require the user to explicitly hide one of the duplicate capabilities via other mechanisms. We can use `TypeError` to print a custom error message at compile-time. We could also pick either side by default.

```
instance (TypeError (Text "Duplicate contents")  -- can be more descriptive
         , In item (Contents a) ~ 'True
         , In item (Contents b) ~ 'True)
         => PairHas item a b 'True 'True where
  getPair = undefined
```

We can also write a custom error message for the case when both sides are false. It is a bit surprising because that contradicts the superclass constraint `(inA || inB) ~ 'True`, but the message does get printed so we won't complain.

```
instance ( TypeError (Text "Not found")  -- can be more descriptive
         , In item (Contents a) ~ 'False
         , In item (Contents b) ~ 'False
         , 'False ~ 'True)
         => PairHas item a b 'False 'False where
  getPair = undefined
```

### Let's cook

Now we can safely write `cook`:

```
cook :: (Smootie, Salad)
cook = let ingredients = [Orange] :& [Cucumber] :& [BlackEyedPeas] in
  (mkSmootie ingredients, mkSalad ingredients)
```

---

You can also see what happens if you duplicate or forget some ingredients

```
cook :: (Smootie, Salad)
cook = let ingredients = [Orange] :& [Cucumber] :& [BlackEyedPeas] :& [Pear] in
  (mkSmootie ingredients, mkSalad ingredients)

-- error: Duplicate contents
```

---

```
cook :: (Smootie, Salad)
cook = let ingredients = [Orange] :& [Cucumber] in
  (mkSmootie ingredients, mkSalad ingredients)

-- error: Not found
```

Comment: I've learn a lot from your response. Thanks so much for the time you took in writing it. One question, in the line 51 of your gist, couldn't we just write `PairHas item a b inA inB => Has item (a :& b)`. I found that this works, but maybe is just by coincidence.

Comment: I was also wondering, aren't there libraries featuring something similar to the `Has` class here. Also I would expect the type family `==` to be defined at `Data.Type.Bool` but for some reason it isn't...

Comment: I didn't know that change works! I'm not quite sure what's going on, although it makes sense since `inA` and `inB` are uniquely determined by the other parameters. There is a `(==)` defined in *base*, in`Data.Type.Equality`, but since base 4.11 it behaves quite differently. In particular `a Equality.== a` does not reduce to `True` when `a` is an uninstantiated variable, as opposed to the one I defined here.